# SharePoint mini calendar view

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-calendar

I would like to have a mini calendar web-part on the page that gets data from the calendar list.

Something like this picture

[image]

Comment: what version of SharePoint? 2010 or 2007?

Comment: Can you code with VS? Are you sticks with SPD? Can you use jQuery? In fact, what are you constraints?

Comment: SP 2010 standard.can use vs,SPD and query. I'd prefer SPD.

Comment: anyone has had similar requirements?

Comment: You can use Calendar rollup web part you can create **See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cV1nydyZ-Ik&feature=youtu.be)**

Answer (score 1):

Had the same wish for my SharePoint environment, but I didn't find anything I liked.

So I took the default stuff and made it "ok".

Two days ago, I posted the english version how I did [that](https://afrait.com/blog/color-calendar-and-icons-in-10-easy-steps-en/).

Maybe it will fit for your requirement, too.

If you like it, please give this post a vote up or mark it as answer if you will do it the same way.[image]

Comment: The link that was given in the solution was broken. kindly please update id possible

Comment: Sorry, link is now up-to-date again

Answer (score 0):

You can try this web part -  [MiniCalendar Web Part](http://minicalendarwebpart.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement and discovered the following useful example for a custom display template using fullcalendar.js:

https://www.pena.id/2014/06/sharepoint-aggregated-calendar-view-using-content-search-web-part-jquery-fullcalendar/

I personally found this quicker and easier to deploy than a custom app plus it integrates nicely with search for cross site collection queries.

Only issue I currently have is the 50 item limit for search results (raised a question here looking for a solution: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128879/sharepoint-cswp-50-item-limithttps://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128879/sharepoint-cswp-50-item-limit)